# How do I know if I am overtraining?

Tags: training

I've plateaued at about body weight bench, squat, deadlift and about eighty percent body weight barbell row. I believe the reason for it maybe that I am overtraining. I go to the gym everday of the week.

How could I reliably check if I am overtraining?